# Erro em programa C, armazenar em vetor;

Tags: c

Boa noite, estou fazendo um programa em c que deve ler 20 entradas com dados de entrevistados.

Consegui elaborar tudo, porém na questão de ler esses dados estou com um erro estranho... (Pode ser coisa do Turbo C)...

Resumindo, Eu consigo inserir alguns registros e depois disso cai de volta para o menu do programa... (Digite uma opção...)

Minhas dúvidas são:

- Essa é a melhor forma de armazenar a entrada de dados?
- O quê eu fiz de errado?

Esse é o script:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>

/*
    - Nome (máximo de 30 caracteres).
    - Idade.
    - Sexo.
    - Quantidade de filhos.
    - Renda mensal familiar.
*/
    struct infoPessoa{
        char nome[30];
        char sexo;
        int idade;
        int nFilhos;
        float renda_familiar;
    };

    // erro estupido por não encontrar referencia...
    void dummy()
    {
        float f,*fp;
        fp=&f;
    }

    void main ()
    {
        // declaração de variaveis
        const int tamanho=20;
        char opcao;
        int i, escolha_valida;
        int saida = 0;
        infoPessoa entrevistados[tamanho]; // 20 pessoas. 

        while( saida == 0 ) {
            escolha_valida = 0;
            while( escolha_valida == 0 ) {
                printf("C - Cadastrar entrevistados:\nL - Listar entrevistados:\nR - Relatorios:\nS - Sair:\n");
                printf("Digite a opcao:\n");
                scanf("   %c", &opcao );
                if((opcao=='C') || (opcao=='L') || (opcao=='R') || (opcao=='S'))
                    escolha_valida = 1;
                else
                    printf("\007Erro. Opcao do menu invalida.\n");
            }

            switch( opcao ) {
                case 'C' :
                    clrscr();

                    for (i=0; i<20; i++)
                    {
                        printf("Digite o nome do entrevistado %d:\n", i+1 );
                        scanf(" %s",entrevistados[i].nome);

                        printf("Digite o sexo (M) OU (F):\n");
                        scanf(" %c", entrevistados[i].sexo);

                        printf("Digite a idade:\n");
                        scanf(" %d", entrevistados[i].idade);

                        printf("Quantos filhos?:\n");
                        scanf(" %d", entrevistados[i].nFilhos);

                        printf("Valor da renda familiar:\n");
                        scanf(" %f", entrevistados[i].renda_familiar);
                    }
                    break;

                case 'L' :
                    clrscr();


                    break;
                case 'R' :

                    /*
                        Com base nos dados coletados, apresente na tela as seguintes informações:
                        - Percentual de mulheres e homens.
                        - Número de pessoas que ganham acima de 500.00 (quinhentos reais).
                        - Percentual de pessoas que tem ao menos 1 filho.
                        - Número de pessoas que nasceram a partir do ano 2000.
                    */
                    break;
                case 'S': saida = 1; break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em **C** não tem a biblioteca `iostream`, então use apenas a `stdio.h`.

A declaração de `entrevistados` está errada, como é uma `struct`, deve declarar como

```
struct infoPessoa entrevistados[tamanho];
```

A repetição `while( escolha_valida == 0 )` é redundante, não deveria ter essa linha no código.

Onde está usando `scanf` não deve haver espaço dentro das aspas:

```
scanf(" %d", &n) // Errado
scanf("%d", &n) // Correto
```

Você também não colocou o `&` na leitura do `char`, do `int` e do `float`. A string não deve ter o `&`.

Para que o sistema faça a leitura do carácter para o sexo, use um `\n` antes do `%c`.

```
scanf("\n%c", &entrevistados[i].sexo);
```